# Is it worth using ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, web, orm, knex.js

I'm using knex, the query builder for the project, but I ran into the problem when using a join, you manually have to mate related data or do separate queries and bind related data so I'm thinking of using ORM but somewhere I heard that they are slower and use the loop for queries under the hood, I use nodejs so it can block threads , and so is it worth using ORM or better mate join data by you self ?

Comment: You're getting caught up in details that don't matter yet. You use an ORM to make your life easier. If it's not helping, figure out if you can add an extension or code to fix that, or find a different ORM that doesn't have the same problem. Node's single-threaded model isn't an issue here. It's a non-blocking event-loop design, just one method for concurrency, but there are many others.

Comment: Most ORMs have some kind of "bypass" mode for when things get really intense and you need to write custom queries. Read the documentation on yours to know its full capabilities before thinking it can't do the job.

Comment: The way you ask the question, I assume your ORM experience is limited.  Some ORMs are very heavy, some are somewhat lighter.  For almost all of them the answer is "it depends on what you are doing".  It is very easy with a ORM to ask for too much data; do you really need that sub-class loaded for all items?  However, in my experience ORMs are "heavy" in a way you haven't thought of . . . they take a while to learn.  You aren't going to just add an ORM and be up in an hour.  You have to look at how useful a ORM will be over the life of the project . . . don't add a ORM for one query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try both using ORM and working without ORM with plain SQL. You will see that 99% [1] of time you are better off with ORM. There are very few projects which are so simple that using ORM is not beneficial.

People you are hearing are wrong or they are using bad ORMs or they are failing to use their choice of ORM properly. Good ORM has well tuned implementations for its data method using, graph algorithms to figure out optimal number of queries for fetching requested data with their relations with as few queries as possible. It wont block event loop unless you have done some slow blocking code in query lifecycle hooks by yourself.

I’ve encountered many times this misconception of ORMs that they will limit your power of doing efficient queries, but it is not true for all ORMs.

Node.js has few light weight ORMs which allows to do common ORMy tasks very easy, but they don’t force you to abstract SQL away. You will still have full power of SQL and even raw queries when ever you need in your hands all the time, but you’ll get to play with relations a lot easier than with plain SQL.

For example you can read / write nested JSON structures efficiently and populate multiple tables easily with single line and to read nested data from database, without having to figure out graph algorithm that optimize number of required queries to fetch the related data and to construct nested data from flat query results.

Finally if you are not using any ORM and set of custom helpers it will harder for other people to get into that code base since it will be full of custom plain SQL + variety helpers.

Disclaimer: I am biased (and know what I’m talking about) since I’ve been maintaining knex query builder for last few years years and I’m involved in development of the only lightweight Node.js ORM which I can recommend: objection.js

[1] Stetson-Harrison 1987